# Installing Samsung network printer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, printing, samsung

I am trying to install Samsung C410W printer on Ubuntu 14.04, however after 2 days of struggling any success. I tried to install it through "Add printer", through adding printer in CUPS and I tried also SULDR. I tried to connect it through WPS to my router what changed the IP address of printer, however after trying to print something I always got "Unable to send data to printer" or "Unable to connect to Network printer". I was hoping in using SyncThru Web Service, however 
`http://ip_address_of_pritner` didn't load. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does Samsung not have any drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote instructions for the m2022w in ubuntu forums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263245&p=13218825#post13218825.php?t=2263245&p=13218825#post13218825

I am quite sure it is similar for all samsung wireless printers.